# Regex in Java with multiple condition to extract arithmetic operator

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expression syntax, after one whole day digging on the google, still can't find a good regex in java to extract the thing I want from a string... 
for example:I have a

```
stringA = "-3.5 + 2 * 3 / 2"
stringB = "2 * 3 / 2 - 3.5";
```

the regex i used was

```
regex="[\\+\\-\\*\\/]", -->choose +,-,*,or / from the target;
```

by doing this, I am able to capture ANY signs in the string including negative sign.

However, I was to capture the negative sign(-) only when it is following by a whitespace.

That is, I want the result from

```
string A as [ +, *, /], these three signs and stringB as [ *, / , -]
```

I realized I only need to add another condition into regex for the negative sign such as

```
regex = "[\\+{\\-\\s}\\*\\/]"  ---> I want to choose same thing but with 
                            extra condition "-"sign has to follow by a whitespace.
```

the square bracket **does not work** like this way..Is there anyone can kindly guide my how to add another condition into the original regex? or write a new regex to qualify the need? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: FYI added detailed explanation to the original answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chi, this might be the simple regex you're looking for:

```
[+*/]|(?<=\s)-
```

**How does it work?**

There is an alternation `|` in the middle, which is a way of saying "match this or match that."

On the left, the character class `[+*/]` matches one character that is a +, * or /

On the right, the lookbehind `(?<=\s)` asserts "preceded by a whitespace character", then we match a minus.

**How to use it?**

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[+*/]|(?<=\\s)-");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

If you are interested, you may want to read up on [regex lookaheads and lookbehinds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: @Chi You are very welcome! Hey, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark and arrow on the left, as this is how the reputation system works. Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO tutorial. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is ditch the class (the `[]` enclosed `Pattern`), use `OR` instead, and use a negative lookahead for your minus sign, to avoid for it to be followed by a digit:

```
String input0 = "2 * 3 / 2 - 3.5";
String input1 = "-3.5 + 2 * 3 / 2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\+|\\-(?!\\d)|\\*|/");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input0);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
System.out.println();
m = p.matcher(input1);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
*
/
-

+
*
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `String#replaceAll()`. Its very simple pattern.

```
    // [any digit] or [minus followed by any digit] or [decimal]
    String regex = "(\\d|-\\d|\\.)";

    String stringA = "-3.5 + 2 * 3 / 2";
    String stringA1 = stringA.replaceAll(regex, "").trim();
    System.out.println(stringA1);

    String stringB = "2 * 3 / 2 - 3.5";
    String stringB1 = stringB.replaceAll(regex, "").trim();
    System.out.println(stringB1);
```

output

```
+  *  /
*  /  -
```

Note : You can get all the operators using `String#split("\\s+")`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution.

Maybe you want to catch the minus sign regardless of white spaces and rather depending on its meaning, i. e. a binary-minus operator and not the minus sign before the numbers.

You could have the case where you could have a binary-minus without any space at all, like in `3-5` or you could have a minus sign before the number with a space between them (which it is allowed in many programming languages, Java included). So, in order to catch your tokens properly (positive-negative-numbers and binary-operators) you can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numberPattern = "(?:-? *\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:E[+-]?\\d+)?)";
    String opPattern = "[+*/-]";
    Pattern tokenPattern = Pattern.compile(numberPattern + "|" + opPattern);


    String stringA = "-3.5 + -2 * 3 / 2";

    Matcher matcher = tokenPattern.matcher(stringA);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group().trim());
    }

}
```

Here you are catching operators AND ALSO operands, regardless of white spaces. If you only need the binary operators, just filter them.

Try with the string `"-3.5+-2*3/2"` (without spaces at all) and you'll have your tokens anyway.